# In R how can I apply if and else if for the following example of two items to a list of items?

Tags: r

Here is the general idea, in practice I'd like to feasibly execute list of [alpha, beta, gamma ... etc] with an arbitrary number of items for each of the subsequent else if statement.

```
if (v == n(r)[alpha]) {
    inc(c)
    v = sample(c(names(r)), 1, replace = FALSE, prob = p[alpha,])
    new = v
    if (new == n(r)[ori]) 
    {
        inc(c)
        dis = b+c
        av = c(av,dis)
    }

else if (v == names(r)[beta]) 
{
    inc(b)
    v = sample(c(n(r)), 1, replace = FALSE, prob = p[beta,])
    new = v
    if (new == n(r)[ori]) 
    {
        inc(b)
        dis = b+c
        av = c(av,dis)
    }  
    else if (v == names(r)[gamma] 
....
```

Comment: Please show a reproducible example

Comment: how can I do if and else if for a list of items (in the statemental part). So there will be as many if and else if as there are of items in a list.

Comment: so for example if (x==a) .... else if (x == b) ... Given a list of (a, b.....c, d ....)

Comment: Have you tried the `switch` function?